# C++ output is wrong. using array and sums

Tags: arrays

I am trying to add up all the numbers in this array that is read from a .txt file. I keep getting a number that isnt the sum... any help please.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std; 

int main()
{
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("program3.txt"); 
    int size; 
    int sum = 0; 
    inFile >> size; 
    //cout << size << endl; 
    int myArray[size]; 

    for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++)
    {
        inFile >> myArray[i]; 
        sum = sum + myArray[i]; 
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << myArray[i] << endl; 
    }
    cout << sum; 
    inFile.close(); 
    return 0;
```

and here is the .txt file with the numbers. The first number is the number of elements in the file and shouldn't be counted as one of the numbers' sum.

```
30
5
9
12
25
847
52
35
62
4
413
82
64
258
35
613
644
21
0
542
-5
9
5
4
2
88
24
26
5
24
55
```

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop has i going from 0 to i <= size. This means i goes from 0 to 30, or 31 values. Changing it to i < size, so that 30 values are counted, should fix your problem.